# DomDocument. Search in the xml file

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to use methods of DomXPath . But I receive strange results:

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//students/group/student/name["sid"]');
foreach ($result as $node) {
    echo "<", $node->tagName, "> : ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
       if ( $node->nodeValue == "sid"){
    echo $node->nodeValue;
    break;
}
}
```

https://ideone.com/AYsVye

Why filter condition does not work?

Comment: ` if ( trim($node->nodeValue) == "sid"){`

Comment: @splash58 Thanks that worked. You should make it an answer.

Comment: i done it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml contains spaces arount node value. To compare them just remove that spaces:

```
if ( trim($node->nodeValue) == "sid") {
```